# Solve task using matrix toolkit java

Tags: mtj

I have matrix A and vector t. And I need to find vector x, so that A*x = t
So there are just 2 steps, convert maxtrix A and vector t to triangle, and then find vector x (or mb it can be done just in one step using this library, idk). How can I do this using MTJ? There is really few documentation or information about MTJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
double[][] matrix = new double[n][n];
double[] vector = new double[n];

Matrix A = new DenseMatrix(matrix);
Vector t = new DenseVector(vector);
Vector x = new DenseVector(n);
A.solve(t,x)
```

And then we will have answer in x